# Determining the Time and Space complexity of a given code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I wish to write code for this problem:

> Given a string, remove duplicates from it in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Now, I have written a code to remove duplicates from a string.

```
public class RemoveDuplicates
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input = "aabbccc";
        char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<inputArray.length;j++)
            {
                if(inputArray[i] == inputArray[j])
                    inputArray[j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        input = new String(inputArray);
        input = input.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        System.out.println("The String after removing duplicates is : "+input);
    }
}
```

Actually, I am taking a character and comparing with the rest, if they are found equal, replace the found character with a space. Finally, remove all the spaces in the string.

I have a basic understanding that it must be **O(n^2)** implementation (with respect to time) because of using two for loops. How do modify my code for **O(n)** time and **O(1)** space complexity?

Or in other words what does **O(1)** space requirement signify? And should I use a single for loop instead of two for the time requirements?

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates that are "not necessarily consecutive", I can't see how it's possible in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: Assuming it's only letters and numbers, you can have 36 boolean variables set to false to begin with. Then when you encounter a certain character, set that boolean to true and then delete all subsequent duplicated characters. This is still O(1) because you predefine a limited number of booleans

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about big O notation, not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(n) means no nested for loop and O(1) means constant storage needed for your input.

If your input string is constrained to be all ASCII then this problem is really simple.

```
`
    boolean[] counter = new boolean[256];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (counter[(int) input.charAt(i)]) {
            sb.setCharAt(i, ' ');
        }
        counter[(int) input.charAt(i)] = true;
    }
`
```

However if the input isn't in ASCII but in Unicode, then it cannot be solved in O(1) space.

Comment: What is constant storage? And can you please explain your code

Comment: Constant storage means storage doesn't vary according to the problem size, in this case, the length of the string.

Comment: Since you have only 256 characters in ASCII, it basically detects if any of them are readily encountered - if yes remove the current character; else set the counter corresponding to the character to be true means it's encountered already. I assume you must know that char can be casted into int.

Comment: Can you come for a personal chat?

Answer (score 0):

If you string is always sorted you can do it with O(n) , and O(1) space .

```
    public String removeDuplicates(String input){

    if(input.length() <= 1){
        return input;
    }
    char[] inputArray = input.toCharArray();

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < input.length(); ++i){

        if(inputArray[i] != inputArray[count]) {
            inputArray[++count] = inputArray[i];
        }
    }


    return String.valueOf(inputArray, 0, count + 1);
}
```

but if it's not sorted you have to sort it.  which takes `O(n lg(n))`

or use hash but it's not for `O(1)` space.

at last you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324175/algorithm-to-determine-if-a-string-has-all-unique-characters/25324405#25324405)

Comment: ...and sorting takes O(n lg n)